# How to change the default icon of $ionicLoading

Tags: ionic-framework

We have created our own loading icon, how do we replace the default spinner with our loading icon.

```
 $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Loading',   
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: false,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 0
      });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

simply add new icon or spinner icon in template otherwise add own gif image using img tag.

```
$ionicLoading.show({
    template: '<ion-spinner icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>',
});
```

in template used any icon.

Answer (score 2):

If you need ionic custom loader spinner:

```
$ionicLoading.show({
template: '<ion-spinner icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>',
});
```

If you need ionic custom image loader :

```
$ionicLoading.show({
   template: '
    <h2>A custom image loader</h2>
    <img src="img/loader.jpg" alt="" width=50" height="50" />
    ',
   content: 'Loading',
   animation: 'fade-in',
   showBackdrop: true,
   maxWidth: 300,
   showDelay: 0
  });
```